# Running task scheduler (cron job) to process a csv file and update DB in Laravel 5.4, Symfony 3.3 and doctrine

Tags: laravel, symfony, cron, doctrine, scheduled-tasks

I am working on a Laravel project that integrated with Symfony 3.3 component and doctrine. 
I need to run a daily task to process a csv file that user uploads to AWS S3 and then update a table in DB accordingly.
My issue is I don't know how to use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface in my ***processCSV command class*** or inject the dependencies into this class?

**My command class looks like this:**

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

use App\Forms\Admin\Type\ConfigType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

use App\Entities\Site;
use App\Entities\LoyaltyParticipation;
use App\Entities\SiteLoyaltyParticipation;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class processCSV extends Command
{   
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'process:csv';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Get and process the CSV file uploaded by admin and update the database.';

    private $process_csv;
    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        .... some code...
        $s3 = Storage::disk('s3');

        $allFileNames = $s3->files('/'. $s3_userCSVFolderUpload);
        .... some code...
        $userCSVFileName = 'filename.csv' // csv file name 

        if($userCSVFileName){
            $contents = $s3->get($s3_userCSVFolderUpload .'/'.$userCSVFileName); 
            $lines = explode("\r", $contents);

            foreach($lines as $key => $line){
                $lineNo = $key + 1;
                $cols = explode("," ,$line);
                if(!empty($cols[0]) ){           
                    if(count($cols) < 4){
                        $error = true;
                        $allErrors .= 'Error'
                        break ;
                    }else{
                        $code = $cols[0]; 
                    }

                $repository = $this->getRepository(Site::class);
                $site = $repository->findOneBy(
                    array(
                        'bpId' =>$code 
                    ) );

                 ...
                 ...
     }
```

When I run the command I get this error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]                    
  Call to undefined method App\Console\Commands\processCSV::getRepository()
```

I know it's wrong to call like that($repository = $this->getRepository) in command class, but couldn't find any solution in my searches.

Your assistance in this matter is greatly appreciated as I am new in symfony and doctrine.

Answer (score 0):

The getRepository method is not defined on your class. 
You need to inject the repository dependency into the __construct method or a setter and create the getRepository method.

Comment: Hi @Aurélien Fontaine and thank you for your reply. I changed the code as follows: private $repo; public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $repo) { parent::__construct(); $this->repo = $repo ;} ...some code in handle()... $repository = $this->repo->getRepository(Site::class);
 $site = $repository->findOneBy( array( 'bpId' =>$code) );  Now I'm getting another error:  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]   
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'vagrant'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Maybe your env by default when you run command is dev and you are not configured the dbal connection for dev correctly. Try --env prod when you execute command

Comment: When I print DB connection parameters ( using print_r($repo->getConnection()->getHost() ) )  in the handle() function, all parameters are okay excecpt HOST. ; it's "127.0.0.1" but the error says host is "localhost". Do you think that's the problem? When I change it to localhost in .env, I get this error: [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]                                      
  An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No handler for this scheme

Comment: Thank you @Aurélien Fontaine, I could inject the dependencies as you said and it worked! I just forgot to run "vagrant ssh" before running my custom command and that was what denying access to DB! Thanks heaps

Answer (score 0):

**I changed my custom command class like so:**

```
class processCSV extends Command
{   
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'process:csv';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Get and process the CSV file uploaded by admin and update the database.';
    private $repo;
    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $repo)
    {
        $this->repo = $repo;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
       ... something

            $repository = $this->repo->getRepository(Site::class);
            $site = $repository->findOneBy(
                array(
                    'bpId' =>$code 
                ) ); 
    }
}
```